# Android throwing a NullPointerException when instantiating SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I'm new at Android development, and I'm trying to create a simple `SharedPreferences` in my (so far only) activity. However, every time I try to run it, I get a Null-Pointer Exception at runtime, even though I assign the variable on the declaration line. My full trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{andyszoke.macrohub/andyszoke.macrohub.SetMacroManualActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3242)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:205)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1695)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6895)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                       at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:111)
                                                       at andyszoke.macrohub.SetMacroManualActivity.<init>(SetMacroManualActivity.java:17)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1690)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2978)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3242) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:205) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1695) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6895) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

and the relevant bits of code:

```
package andyszoke.macrohub;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SetMacroManualActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "myMessage";
    private static final String MY_PREF = "MyPreferences";
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREF, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
```

The exception is thrown at the third line in the class. I've tried all sorts of different combinations of declarations and looked at as many stackoverflow posts as I could find but nothing is ironing it out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Move the `prefs`  and `editor` initializations to `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for setting up shared preferences is running before the onCreate. For all normal purposes, only variables should be assigned before the onCreate. When you have said this.getSharedPreferences, the word 'this' is referring to the activity, but the onCreate has not been called yet (so the activity has not yet been formed). So 'this' is being assigned to a null object. So the NullPointerException is obtained.

```
public class SetMacroManualActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private static final String TAG = "myMessage";
  private static final String MY_PREF = "MyPreferences";
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // load the layout
    setContentView(R.layout.filters); 
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
```

MODE_PRIVATE is what is usually used, there are other modes based on requirements. So please check what is fine for you.

Comment: This predictably causes errors in my load and save methods elsewhere in the program, outside of onCreate. Is it acceptable to simply pass the SharedPreferences and Editor objects as parameters? I haven't seen that done in any tutorials or explanations

Comment: @AndrewSzoke Just move the initializations to `onCreate()`. Leave the declarations where they were.

Comment: @MikeM. I think that did it. Or at least I'm getting unrelated exceptions now so it's compiling down the program. Thanks!